# How to construct weak-star convergence?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

From partial derivative as vector basis $\left\{\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}, i=1,\ldots,n\right\}$. How to contruct sequence $\{u_i\}, i=1,\ldots, n$ such that:

1, $u_i \stackrel{w^*}\rightarrow 0$ and $\|u_i\|=1$

2, $u_i \bot \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_j} \forall j\in\{1,\ldots, n\}$

I have the answer for dimension =1. I consider $f: \mathbb R^n\rightarrow X$, X: Banach space.

My question related to Chapter XII Joe Diestel's book Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It would help those who don't have access to this book if you said which space/norm is under consideration.

Comment: @julien: X: Infinite dimensional Banach space.

Comment: Where do $u_i$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ live? A priori, the latter is a function with values in $X$. So your comment did not help much...

Comment: $u_i$ as linear functional, and $\frac{ \partial f}{\partial x_j} is in $X$.